# How to post a message via Slack-App from c#, as a user not App, with attachment, in a specific channel

Tags: c#, slack, slack-api

I can not for the life of me post a message to another channel than the one I webhooked. And I can not do it as myself(under my slackID), just as the App.

Problem is I have to do this for my company, so we can integrate slack to our own Software. I just do not understand what the "payload" for JSON has to look like (actually I'm doing it exactly like it says on Slack's Website, but it doesn't work at all - it always ignores things like "token", "user", "channel" etc.).

I also do not understand how to use the url-methods like "https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage" - where do they go? As you might see in my code I only have the webhookurl, and if I don't use that one I can not post to anything. Also I do not understand how to use arguments like a token, specific userId, a specific channel... - if I try to put them in the Payload they are just ignored, it seems.

Okay, enough whining! I'll show you now what I got so far. This is from someone who posted this online! But I changed and added a few things:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Task.WaitAll(IntegrateWithSlackAsync());
        }

        private static async Task IntegrateWithSlackAsync()
        {
            var webhookUrl = new Uri("https://hooks.slack.com/services/TmyHook");  
            var slackClient = new SlackClient(webhookUrl);
            while (true)
            {
                Console.Write("Type a message: ");
                var message = Console.ReadLine();
                Payload testMessage = new Payload(message);
                var response = await slackClient.SendMessageAsync(testMessage);
                var isValid = response.IsSuccessStatusCode ? "valid" : "invalid";
                Console.WriteLine($"Received {isValid} response.");
                Console.WriteLine(response);
            }
        }
    }
}

public class SlackClient
{
        private readonly Uri _webhookUrl;
        private readonly HttpClient _httpClient = new HttpClient {};

        public SlackClient(Uri webhookUrl)
        {
            _webhookUrl = webhookUrl;
        }

        public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendMessageAsync(Payload payload)
        {

            var serializedPayload = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(payload);

            var stringCont = new StringContent(serializedPayload, Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

            var response = await _httpClient.PostAsync(_webhookUrl, stringCont);

            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

I made this class so I can handle the Payload as an Object:

```
    public class Payload
{
    public string token = "my token stands here";
    public string user = "my userID";
    public string channel = "channelID";
    public string text = null;

    public bool as_user = true;


    public Payload(string message)
    {
        text = message;
    }
}
```

I would be so appreciative for anyone who could post a complete bit of code that really shows how I would have to handle the payload. And/or what the actual URL would look like that gets send to slack... so I maybe can understand what the hell is going on :)

Comment: There are two kinds of webhooks. The standard one is fixed to a channel. check this post for details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51467673/4379151

Comment: So if you install and use the incoming webhook app from the app directory, you can use different channels and usernames. However, I would recommend to use the web API method`chat.postMessage` if you can. Its the only approach that solves your problem and works with a Slack app.

Comment: here is a c# example class for sending message via incoming webhook: https://gist.github.com/jogleasonjr/7121367

Comment: The Github-example is out of date, it doesn't work like that anymore with slack.
Just wnated to let you know.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**1. Incoming webhook vs. chat.postMessage**

The incoming webhook of a Slack app is always fixed to a channel. There is legacy variant of the [Incoming Webhook](https://api.slack.com/custom-integrations/incoming-webhooks) that supports overriding the channel, but that has to be installed separately and will not be part of your Slack app.  (see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51467215/sending-message-to-different-channel-via-slack-webhook-fails/51467673#51467673)).

So for your case you want to use the web API method [`chat.postMessage`](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage) instead.

**2. Example implementation**

Here is a very basic example implementation for sending a message with `chat.postMessage` in C#. It will work for different channels and messages will be send as the user who owns the token (same that installed the app), not the app.

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Text;

public class SlackExample
{    
    public static void SendMessageToSlack()
    {        
        var data = new NameValueCollection();
        data["token"] = "xoxp-YOUR-TOKEN";
        data["channel"] = "blueberry";        
        data["as_user"] = "true";           // to send this message as the user who owns the token, false by default
        data["text"] = "test message 2";
        data["attachments"] = "[{\"fallback\":\"dummy\", \"text\":\"this is an attachment\"}]";

        var client = new WebClient();
        var response = client.UploadValues("https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage", "POST", data);
        string responseInString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response);
        Console.WriteLine(responseInString);        
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        SendMessageToSlack();
    }
}
```

This is a very rudimentary implementation using synchronous calls. Check out [`this question`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4015346/4379151) for how to use the more advanced asynchronous approach.

Comment: Wow, thank you very much! I wasn't expecting an answer so soon. And on top of that it's a really explicit one! I'll get to it and try it as soon as I find time. And then I'll obviously will give feedback on this. Thank you so much!

Comment: Awesome man! I just tried your code - it worked flawlessly. You helped me so much. Now I'll try to figure out how to get this working for other users than my self. I'm still a little unclear on how the tokens work, since I only have one for the App. But if I get stuck again, I might post another question. 
Again, thank you so much - you made my day!

Comment: Happy to help! If you want to send message on behalf of other users [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42663007/4379151) might be helpful.

Comment: Now I also got the async approach working - thank god! :D Or better, thank you.
I'll try to figure out how to attach files to the messages now... 
Thank you so far, have a nice weekend.

Comment: Well done. Hint: You can only attach images to messages (in the attachments). Other files need to be uploaded via `files.upload` API method.

Comment: How do I get that `xoxp-YOUR-TOKEN`? This is a user token, not an "App" API token, right? https://api.slack.com/authentication/token-types talks about "User Tokens", but doesn't specify how to get them. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53129239 talks about App tokens, not User tokens...

Answer (score 8):

Here is an improved example on how send a Slack message with attachments.

This example is using the better **async** approach for sending requests and the message incl. attachments is constructed from C# objects.

Also, the request is send as modern JSON Body POST, which requires the TOKEN to be set in the header.

Note: Requires [Json.Net](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json)

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SlackExample
{
    class SendMessageExample
    {
        private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        // reponse from message methods
        public class SlackMessageResponse
        {
            public bool ok { get; set; }
            public string error { get; set; }
            public string channel { get; set; }
            public string ts { get; set; }
        }

        // a slack message
        public class SlackMessage
        {
            public string channel{ get; set; }
            public string text { get; set; }
            public bool as_user { get; set; }
            public SlackAttachment[] attachments { get; set; }
        }

        // a slack message attachment
        public class SlackAttachment
        {
            public string fallback { get; set; }
            public string text { get; set; }
            public string image_url { get; set; }
            public string color { get; set; }
        }

        // sends a slack message asynchronous
        // throws exception if message can not be sent
        public static async Task SendMessageAsync(string token, SlackMessage msg)
        {
            // serialize method parameters to JSON
            var content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(msg);
            var httpContent = new StringContent(
                content,
                Encoding.UTF8,
                "application/json"
            );

            // set token in authorization header
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);

            // send message to API
            var response = await client.PostAsync("https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage", httpContent);

            // fetch response from API
            var responseJson = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            // convert JSON response to object
            SlackMessageResponse messageResponse =
                JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SlackMessageResponse>(responseJson);

            // throw exception if sending failed
            if (messageResponse.ok == false)
            {
                throw new Exception(
                    "failed to send message. error: " + messageResponse.error
                );
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {           
            var msg = new SlackMessage
            {
                channel = "test",
                text = "Hi there!",
                as_user = true,
                attachments = new SlackAttachment[] 
                {
                    new SlackAttachment
                    {
                        fallback = "this did not work",
                        text = "This is attachment 1",
                        color = "good"
                    },

                    new SlackAttachment
                    {
                        fallback = "this did not work",
                        text = "This is attachment 2",
                        color = "danger"
                    }
                }
            };

            SendMessageAsync(
                "xoxp-YOUR-TOKEN",                
                msg
            ).Wait();

            Console.WriteLine("Message has been sent");
            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }

}
```