# How to properly format attachment data for Slack chat.postMessage

Tags: c#, slack, slack-api

I am trying to incorporate a slack notification using a Slack bot app API into my C# application. The code below is working fine but the format used for the `attachments` field makes it very difficult to edit and maintain... There must be an easier way to populate that json array?

I've tried multiple ways to write it but I can't get it to work properly other than with this unwieldy syntax.

```
var data = new NameValueCollection
        {
            ["token"] = "token", // Removed my actual token from here obviously
            ["channel"] = "channel", // Same with the channel
            ["as_user"] = "true",
            ["text"] = "test message 2",
            ["attachments"] = "[{\"fallback\":\"dummy\", \"text\":\"this is an attachment\", \"color\":\"#F35A00\", \"title\" : \"Title\", \"title_link\": \"http://www.google.com\"}]"
        };

var client = new WebClient();
var response = client.UploadValues("https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage", "POST", data);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "unwieldy" syntax is hand-crafted JSON and a much better approach would be to construct the attachments as C# objects and then convert them into JSON as the API requires.

My example is using the external library [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) for the JSON conversion.

Example for C# object:

```
// a slack message attachment
public class SlackAttachment
{
    public string fallback { get; set; }
    public string text { get; set; }
    public string image_url { get; set; }
    public string color { get; set; }
}
```

Example for creating a new `attachments` array:

```
var attachments = new SlackAttachment[] 
{
    new SlackAttachment
    {
        fallback = "this did not work",
        text = "This is attachment 1",
        color = "good"
    },

    new SlackAttachment
    {
        fallback = "this did not work",
        text = "This is attachment 2",
        color = "danger"
    }
};
```

Finally, converting the `attachments` array to JSON for the API:

```
var attachmentsJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(attachments);
```

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53328625/4379151) for a complete example.

Comment: That did it! Thanks for the help